# Typo3 - Indexed Search how to order results by page title?

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x

Inside the advanced options of the Indexed Search result page, there is an option to order results. While all other options are working fine, the two fields inside "Order by" have no influence on the results order.

The configuration page of indexed search has an option "basic.flagBitMask" where it says you can increase the importance of  and  tags, but setting it to "128" to increase the title importance has no influence at all.

How to get this options working or is there another option to show results with the searchword in the title on top of the results list?

I used the default index_search.tmpl which comes along with the extension.
The Typo3 version is 7.6.6, Indexed Search version is 7.6.0.

Answer (score 1):

This problem seems to be a [bug](https://forge.typo3.org/issues/58134). In current versions of Indexed Search ordering is not possible when MySQL driver for Indexed Search Engine (indexed_search_mysql) is used.